# Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired - occurs every minute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application that is dying on our test web server (single IIS7).  It appears that IIS is unable to keep sessions alive.  A survey of the Event Log show:

"Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired."

Interestingly this is happening every almost exactly every 1 min.

Web.config appears to be good, and I've checked .NET's machine.config--which doesn't have any references to validationKey autogenerate.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the parts of the web.config that are partinent to authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an Information-level message and can be filtered out using the suggestions in this thread:

[Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686324/forms-authentication-failed-for-the-request-reason-the-ticket-supplied-has-exp)