# Forms Authentication: Determine why ticket is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, windows-server-2012

I have a web application that uses Forms Authentication. The application is MVC and also has a section for requests from our Mobile application. The mobile application for a client was unused for a while and came back and now I see this logged in event view:

Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

I'm also logging cookies in IIS and see that ASPXAUTH looks right and that comes in on the first request. Then, at the Authorize attribute it redirects to login page and generates that error message.

The problem I have is we cannot have the client re-authenticate through log in on mobile app as that will cause data loss which is not an option in our case.

So my question is, is there a way to identify why it is invalid. Such as, expired token, invalid token, etc? I'm asking because I have researched and there are different ways to approach this depending on which reason. Such as machine key issues, etc...

Other details:
Machine Key on IIS: Automatically generates at runtime, and unique by application. AutoGenerate, IsolateApps is entered for both validation and decryption.

FormsAuthenticationTicket expiration is set to int.MaxValue when it was originally generated.

It is very difficult to reproduce. I wasn't originally able to reproduce this for a while. Last night it seemingly at random happened, so now I have a mobile app that is stuck getting this invalid ticket error to test with.

I have looked at this post:
[ASP.NET Forms Authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266578/asp-net-forms-authentication-failed-for-the-request-reason-the-ticket-supplied)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Machine Key on IIS: Automatically generates at runtime

is probably the reason. If your machine key is not static then it would get regenerated every time your app pool is recycled. Once that happens it will invalidate all of your existing logins.

Comment: Yes, I tested by restarting iis and noticed it was invalidating tokens.Unchecked and works now. Thank you!

Comment: @jazzmasterkc - can you explain further, unchecked what?

Comment: @Rick this was quite a long time ago, but I believe you can get to it by going to IIS -> Click on your server -> In the main area click on "Machine Key" -> Uncheck "Automatically gerate at runtime". This could also be done at the site level.