# Forms authentication fails with "Forms authentication failed for the request." at random

Tags: c#, .net, iis, model-view-controller, .net-4.5

We are facing an error on our server's where the logged in user's are signed out at random, even though sliding expiration is set, with the below error on Event Logs

> Event code: 4005
>   Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

This happens on Windows 2019 Datacenter server, .net 4.5, IIS-10.
I have already tried using **manually generated machine keys**, but it doesn't help

Comment: did you check what is the time out of your tickets? You can set the timeout and expiration policy (e.g. sliding, absolute) in your web/machine.config under /configuration/system.web/authentication/forms. this is, not an error just information. you could refer this link for more detail:[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266578/asp-net-forms-authentication-failed-for-the-request-reason-the-ticket-supplied) ,[link2](https://forums.asp.net/t/1762166.aspx?forms+authentication+failed+for+the+request+reason+the+ticket+supplied+was+invalid)

Comment: yeah, its a sliding expiration with 15 mins, but the users are being logged out prior to that, and this informational message is logged when that happens. the same timeout works perfectly with the same code on a different server (Win 2012 R2 Standard)

Comment: Could you share your form authentication setting and detailed code of the form authentication? did you refer the suggested link?

Comment: form auth settings is like
`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="URL" requireSSL="true" timeout="15" />
    </authentication>`
the auth code validates the user using the Membership provider, then an auth cookie is set using
`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, persistent)`
Also, I have checked those links prior, and they weren't helpful

Comment: could you share what is your application pool recycling setting? also, you can try comparing the difference between the problem server and
that server which works well.